# HttpWebRequest doesn't work: unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, getresponse

TLS is TLS 1.3, Linux server.
Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
error: unexpected error occurred on a receive
'''

```
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://example.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=aptk0012&password=9875322");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            string post_data = "Basic VV9mZ.....";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", post_data);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

'''
But Postman does it.

Pls help me here!!!

full error detail is here:

```
'''See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.ND_Get_Token(String username, String password, LabelControl lbMessage, Boolean is_show_msg) in C:\Users\orgil\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 512
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.btGetEMDToken_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\orgil\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 488
```

'''

Comment: Post the *actual, full error*, not just some words from the message. You can get the full error with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on the `Copy Details` link in the exception's popup while debugging

Comment: Why is `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288` used? Are you trying to force the use of TLS1.2 on an unsupported .NET Framework version?

Comment: error detail inserted

Comment: Server has TLS 1.3, my client computer has .NET 4.0

Comment: Internet said that 12288 is value for Tls13

Comment: .NET 4.0 is unsupported and didn't even support TLS1.2. You can't make it work with an encryption algorithm it knows nothing about. The oldest supported .NET Old version is 4.5.2. You should have upgraded to a supported version years ago - major services dropped support for anything less than TLS1.2 almost 5 years ago

Comment: While 4.5.2 is the oldest supported version, you shouldn't try to use anything less than 4.7.2 - 4.6.something was the first version to support TLS1.2 automatically but versions before 4.7.2 had problems with .NET Standard 2.0 packages.

Comment: As for the server requiring TLS1.3 are you sure? The standard was only finalized this year, so the server can't realistically demand clients use TLS1.3 only - unless it uses a pre-release version. In any case, that support is [provided by the operating system](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/microsoft-tls-1-3-support-reference/), which means you'll have to ensure the OS supports TLS1.3. It's quite likely that the server supports TLS1.2 too though. Again, you need an up-to-date version of .NET and OS

Comment: You other posting said Postman worked.  When Net version are changed the defaults also change which could break old code.  So use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working Postman with non working c#.  Check TLS version and headers in first request.

Comment: It is in Postman that TLS protocol = TLSv1.3 after sending successfully. Then I think the server has TLSv1.3, isn't it?